# Issue with Filtering data With Filter Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-pipelines, etl, azure-data-factory

I am trying to filter the following folders using filter activity and select only the latest date from entire blob Container.

[image]

Folder Names example: 2020-04-21, 2021-08-11, 2020-01-07

I need to select 2021-08-11

I am using Get metadata (ChildItems) activity to get folder names and using following logic to filter them in filter activity.

```
@greater(max(array(int(replace(item().name, '-', '')))),0)
```

But after filter I am getting all folders as they are.
I know my logic is scuffed, but I am beginner in ADF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do first get Metadata to get full list of folders, use ForEach to find the latest folder and assign the folder name to a variable, finally do the copy data using the variable, which now stores your latest folder name.

Parent pipeline:
[image]

output of GetMetadata:

[image]

Dynamic content used in ForEach: `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

The forEach contains only 1 if condition activity:
[image]

The expression used is imilar to yours: `@greater(int(replace(item().name, '-', '')), int(replace(variables('latestFolder'),'-','')))`

Inside the true case, there is only the variable assignment:
[image]

finally use the variable, which now contains the latest folder's folder name, in the
copy activity:
[image]

Comment: I get what you did there and seems that it should work. but something is causing the pipeline to fail.  here's the Screenshot https://ibb.co/NCjbNJH

Comment: Thats a rather vague exception. Can you show us where it appears in ADF **through editting your question**? (i.e. which activity throws this exception)

Comment: Check in the monitor tab, you will get detailed exception. I guess its something to do with the expression.

Comment: It throws an exception as soon as I start debug. so even before pipeline run starts https://ibb.co/b3kX7sL

Comment: You may want to remove some of the block and start simple first to isolate the problematic part. Also, please update your question with the current expression you used, preferrably settings/expressions in every activity block.

Comment: You can debug one by one activity and isolate the issue. Then you can post the settings of that activity

Comment: It Worked, it was my silly mistake in set variable that caused the problem. Thank you so much both of you , appreciate the good work!!